# How to mantain a file intact after declaring L=open(...) and then W=open(...,'w')

Tags: python, file

I have got my code *j.py* and a text file *j.txt*.

```
#I have something written in j.txt
L=open('j.txt') #I define this variable because will use it multiple times later
W=open('j.txt','w') #I define this variable because will use it multiple times later
for line in L:
    print(line)
L.close()
W.write('abc')
W.close()
```

But nothing will be printed. As it looks like the mere act of defining `W=open('j.txt','w')` will immediately trigger the action 'w' of rewriting the file *j.txt*.

Is there a way to solve it? I mean, only effectively write with W mode when commanding something like `W.write('anything')`?

Comment: Open the j.txt in `w` mode after the printing

Comment: In general, it is a better idea to write to a new, temporary file, then replace the original with the temporary file in one atomic move after you are sure the writes all succeeded. That said, you might try opening`j.txt` in `rw` mode instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use 'r+' mode.
‘r+’ is special read and write mode, which is used to handle both actions when working with a file.
Try something like this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
   d = f.read()
   print d
   f.seek(0)
   f.write("some data")
   f.truncate()
```